# Using LINQ to select values from a list based on values from joined list

Tags: linq, join

I have a model which involves a set of units. Each unit has a set of numbers. I'm writing a provider method that returns a list of units that contain any of the given numbers.

There are two tables involved in the query - the `Units` table, and the `NumberUnits` table. The `NumberUnits` table links the `Units` to the `Numbers` (but since we already know the numbers required, we're not interested in them).

I currently have this:

```
var a =  (from units in DataProvider.Units
    join numUnits in DataProvider.NumberUnits on units.Id equals numUnits.Unit
    where numbers.Contains(numUnits.Number)
    select units);
```

Where `numbers` is the list of numbers we are searching with. I want to return any `Unit` that has a `NumberUnit` found in the list of numbers, but this is returning nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some sample data? It looks like what you have should work...

Comment: The Unit and NumberUnit tables are pretty big, but I'll give an example. Say we have Units A, B and C. Unit A has numbers 11 and 12 attached to it through a NumberUnit entry, B has 12 and 13 and C has 13 and 14. If 'numbers' contained numbers 11 and 12 the query should return Units A and B but not C.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm just an idiot. That works just fine, turns out I have some data issues where a huge portion of my units that are supposed to have entries in the numberunits table do not.